# Spacing Error in List of Figures and Tables

Tags: table-of-contents, lists

I am using overleaf and when commanding '\listoffigures' and '\listoftables' the first value of the list has improper spacing.

I have tried various different versions of '\setlength{\cft____}{0.4cm}' and found that the only one doing anything to change it is the '\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.4cm}'. I have tried using '\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\renewcommand*\protect\addvspace[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke8PG.png){}}'
'\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace}'
but did not see any change in the first items in the list.

[image: Incorret Spacing of Figure Titles]

Comment: I take it by the reference to \cft that you are using tocloft.  Does the problem remain if you remove tocloft?  Are there any conflicting packages (like KOMA)?  A full MWE would really help here.

Comment: please always supply an example that shows the problem. It is very hard to debug a screenshot of a fragment of output,